# Starting Emulator for API level 27 through CLI, Missing emulator engine program for 'x86' CPU

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-sdk-tools

After upgrading to API level 27, the `emulator @test` command is no longer working.

It throws a `PANIC: Missing emulator engine program for 'x86' CPU.` error

Emulator of API level 26 still works with the same command.

SDKManager is of version 26.1.1

Comment: Check for update and download the emulator image.

Comment: Yea, currently on emulator image is on `system-images;android-27;google_apis;x86`, was just previously using `system-images;android-26;google_apis;x86` downloaded through `sdkmanager` CLI. As of the latest version, still not working :/

Answer (score 26):

It's because the emulator executable is present in 2 different paths now. Earlier it was in `${ANDROID_SDK_ROOT}/tools`, now the preferred executable is in `${ANDROID_SDK_ROOT}/emulator`.

**Solution:** add `${ANDROID_SDK_ROOT}/emulator` to you `PATH` environment variable, and make sure it is present before `${ANDROID_SDK_ROOT}/tools` so that it has the priority.

Comment: Worked for me, thanks, I want to  try same way on  osx will it work?

Comment: @ArchilLabadze yes, it works on mac too. I'm currently using it on may mac.

Comment: Thanks a lot, adding emulator to PATH, just before tools worked.

Comment: Confirmed. This worked for Linux as well. now it runs the emulator directly from ionic with live reload. Thanks!!